# Why is Plunker not loading AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, plunker

I opened a clean plunker editor, added Angular to it and wrote an expression. It does not work however.

The [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/1toaYAuabUm1BEwTPdjl?p=preview).

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>



    <head data-ng-app="">
        <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js"></script>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
        <div>
          {{ 1 + 1 }}
        </div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

I am new to both Angular and Plunker. I'm using Firefox. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try using ng-app instead of data-ng-app, it's better practise to define the ng-app at the `<html>`-tag... So try using `<html ng-app="myApp">`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you put `data-ng-app=""` on the `<head>` tag rather than `<body>` which is where your `{{ 1 + 1 }}` is. Since it doesn't know there's supposed to be an app there, Angular doesn't evaluate that expression and leaves it as `{{ 1 + 1 }}` rather than 2.

You are also using Angular 2.0 rather than the current release, which is a complete remake of Angular compared to the current release. Adding a script tag for the current release `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think I fixed it

Comment: @user2969329 Also, i noticed that you used Angular 2.0 rather than the current release. I'm not entirely sure about the Angular 2.0 syntax, but if you add a link to the current release using `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the angular script from google cdn.

You need to add a module on the script.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

and also add a reference for the module in the html page

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

See updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ObpHaAeV9UXITNiCbhqf?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, it's actually the "myApp" part that did it, I moved the ng-app around several times already, it's been everywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `New`->`AngularJS` for create correct angular plunker projects;

[image]